# using DefaultListMethod to make custom buttons via showOptionDialog

Tags: java, eclipse

I am just learning AWT / Swift / JavaFx recently and I feel like I have learned a lot but have barely scratched the surface. There might be a much easier way to do this BUT, I am trying to make a GUI button in eclipse that calculates the distance between two objects that the user creates. Lets call them Robots for now. So, I have one button that allows the user to create the Robots and it stores them in a DefaultListModel (listModel) and displays them in a Jlist (list) below the buttons. When the user then clicks on a robot, another button becomes actice and allows them to calculate the distance between them (one of the parameters of the robots is their location on a grid). I have all that worked out but my problem is that I am trying to make it to where they have to select two different Robots. At first I thought I could let them select two Robots and then make the computeDistance button becomes active, but I am not really sure how to do that because the only way I can select more than one object in the JList is to cntrl click and I don't want the user to have to know that trick.

My next idea was to allow the user to have one Robot selected and then give them a popup window displaying the other Robots and have them select one. Via showOptionsDialog, I have discovered how to make a custom JOptionPane, so I thought, why not make them buttons (probably will look awful, but I don't know how to make anything other than `JOptionPane.showXxx` at this point (like I said, only skin deep so far). Have tried consulting the javadocs, but right now that is a LOTTT to take in and have read a decent amount, I thought.

Ok, sorry if this is long, but is there a way, using my DefaultListMethod to make custom buttons? I tried a bunch of ways by creating `Object[] options = {list.elements()};` etc but that doesn't work. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: *"is to cntrl click and I don't want the user to have to know that trick."* that's actually a common user interface interaction

Comment: Maybe, on the first selection, you could populate s textField, on the second selection, you could populate another textField, but you'll need a clear button to rest the fields

Comment: My question to your first response would then be: how do I get the values from the two selected items in the list? When I use list.getSelectedValue() I can get the first object but I don't know how to make it where I can get the second? Is there a +1 solution or something along those lines? Maybe I'll try that ha. Second q: is there a way to only activate the button if two items are selected? Thanks!

Comment: [getSelectedValuesList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValuesList())